# Iterate over pair lines and count using python

Tags: python, for-loop, split, iterator, pattern-matching

I have a text file that looks like:

```
>MN00153:75:000H37WNG:1:11102:13823:1502
CCTGCGTTGAAGTGGCTTACTTGCACCTTATGCTACCGTGACCTGCGAATCCAGTCTCATCGTGACCATTCAGGACCAGTGGCAAGAGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACCGCTCATTATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTT
CASP3_fw1_rc : CCATTCAGGACCAGTGGCAAG - The position is 66
CASP3_fw2 : CCTGCGTTGAAGTGGCTTACT - The position is 1
Distance is 44

>MN00153:75:000H37WNG:1:11102:13823:1504
CCTGCGTTGAAGTGGCTTACTTGCACCTTATGCTACCGTGACCTGCGAATCCAGTCTCATCGTGACCATTCAGGACCAGTGGCAAGAGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACCGCTCATTATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTT
CASP3_fw1_rc : CCATTCAGGACCAGTGGCAAG - The position is 66
CASP3_fw2 : CCTGCGTTGAAGTGGCTTACT - The position is 1
Distance is 44

>MN00153:75:000H37WNG:1:11102:13823:1506
CCTGCGTTGAAGTGGCTTACTTGCACCTTATGCTACCGTGACCTGCGAATCCAGTCTCATCGTGACCATTCAGGACCAGTGGCAAGAGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACCGCTCATTATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTT
CASP3_fw1_rc : CCATTCAGGACCAGTGGCAAG - The position is 66
CASP3_fw2_rc : CCTGCGTTGAAGTGGCTTACT - The position is 1
Distance is 44

>MN00153:75:000H37WNG:1:11102:13823:1508
CCTGCGTTGAAGTGGCTTACTTGCACCTTATGCTACCGTGACCTGCGAATCCAGTCTCATCGTGACCATTCAGGACCAGTGGCAAGAGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACCGCTCATTATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTT
CASP3_fw1_rc : CCATTCAGGACCAGTGGCAAG - The position is 66
EIF2_fw2 : CCTGCGTTGAAGTGGCTTACT - The position is 1
Distance is 44
```

I am interested in lines 3 and 4 of each bucket (starts with '>'). I want to count 1 if line 3 and line 4 is CASP3 (regardless of what is afterward). so the output should be

```
3
```

Because first, second, and third buckets have pair CASP3 in lines 3 and 4 of each bucket (except the last one).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your file is not too huge you might use `.readlines` function to get `list` of lines following way:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

then use `enumerate` and `str` methods following way:

```
cnt = 0
for inx, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.startswith('>') and lines[inx+2].startswith('CASP3') and lines[inx+3].startswith('CASP3'):
        cnt += 1
print(cnt)
```

My solution requires that there are at least 3 lines after last line starting with `>`.

Comment: Thank you for your great solution. Would it be possible to use your code also in a way that if ```[inx+2]``` and ```[inx+3]``` are not similar  (just the part before the first ```_```) then get a count for that?

Answer (score 2):

Without reading the whole file into memory:

```py
def startswith_casp(iterator):
    # grab the next four lines of your file
    chunk = [line for _, line in zip(range(3), iterator)]
    # use a slice here to avoid index errors
    return all(c.startswith('CASP3') for c in chunk[1:3])
        
with open('yourfile.txt') as fh:
    count = 0

    for line in fh:
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        elif line.startswith('>'):
            # Function returns a boolean, so True will add 1 while False adds 0
            count += startswith_casp(fh)
        else:
            continue

print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

It would probably help if you were to explain what you already tried. That being said here's a general approach:

- Use the `.split()` method to split at any character(s) you want. This results in you getting a list with each entry being one bucket.
- Loop over this list with `for VariableName in ExampleList:` to check each bucket on their own.
- You can optionally check if the first entry is a `>` or if you did the splitting correctly you may not need to.
- Seperate each bucket into another list where each entry is one line by using `bucket.splitlines()`.
- Then check if the first characters of the 3rd and 4th entry in this list are `CASP3` by checking if `string[2][:5]=="CASP3"`(for the third line) and `string[3][:5]=="CASP3"`(for the fourth line) is true.
- Add another counter to the function that is increased by 1 whenever one bucket is valid.
- return this counter.

If you have additional questions, feel free to ask.

**Here's a example that takes a string and returns your value you need:**

```
def getValue(string):
    counter=0
    splitList=string.split("\n\n")
    for bucket in splitList:
        bucket=bucket.splitlines()
        if bucket[2][:5]=="CASP3" and bucket[3][:5]=="CASP3":
            counter+=1
return counter
```

Note that this function relies on the buckets being seperated by a empty newline, but you can change that as well to seperate on any other character(s).

Answer (score 1):

Here I am `split`-ing by `\n\n` to get the "buckets", then by `\n` to get the lines within each bucket, then checking the 3rd (`[2]`) and 4th (`[3]`) line in each bucket for the pattern:

```
with open('genes.txt') as file:
    data = file.read()

by_bucket = [i.split('\n') for i in data.split('\n\n')]

count = 0
for bucket in by_bucket:
    count += (bucket[2].startswith('CASP3') and bucket[3].startswith('CASP3'))

print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is reading the file.txt into a dictionary of text sections (where a section spans between the two *greater than* symbols (i.e. '>') which then allows you to easily perform some comparisons.

```
file_path = './file.txt'
keyword="CASP3"
section_ID = 0
count = 0
all_sections = {}

with open(file_path,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith(">"):
            if line not in all_sections:
                section_ID += 1
                all_sections[section_ID] = {}
                all_sections[section_ID]['entries'] = []
        all_sections[section_ID]['entries'].append(line)

for sec_id in all_sections:
    if all_sections[sec_id]['entries'][2].startswith(keyword) and all_sections[sec_id]['entries'][3].startswith(keyword):
        count+=1
print('count : ', count)
```

output using your file would be :

> count :  3